# Global variable loses its value after providing its value in a function.Unable to access its value outside that function

Tags: java

Actually i declared a globval variable "jjj" String type with a initial value "lo", i provide its vaue in the function prant() but i am unable to access its value outside this function prant() in jButton6ActionPerformed code.

```
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author prashant
 */
public class Avg_Game extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Avg_Game() {

        initComponents();
    }
    public  Avg_Game(String Om){
        pop = Om;
        initComponents();
    }
    String pop;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public String jjj = "lo";

    int[] mat[];
    int[] mat_sol[];
    int n,sqn,k;

    public Avg_Game(int n,int k) {
               /// String jjj;
        this.n = n;
        this.k = k;
                int m;
        Double sqnd = Math.sqrt(n);
        sqn = sqnd.intValue();
        mat = new int[n][n];
        mat_sol = new int[n][n];
               initComponents();
        }

    private void fillValue() {
        for(int i = 0;i < n;i = i + sqn) {
            fillBox(i,i);
            }
        fillRemaining(0,sqn);
        for(int j = 0;j < n;j++) {
            for(int k = 0;k < n;k++) {
                mat_sol[j][k] = mat[j][k];
            }
        }
               // this.mat = mat;
        removeKDigits();        //remove randomly k digits.
                //jTextField26.setText(mat[1][0]);
        }

    boolean unUsedInBox(int rowstart,int colstart,int num) {        //rreturn false if given 3*3 box contains num
        for(int i = 0;i<sqn;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j<sqn;j++) {
                if(mat[rowstart + i][colstart + j] == num) {
                    return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        return true;
        }

    void fillBox(int row,int col) {
        int num;
        for(int i = 0;i<sqn;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<sqn;j++) {
                do {
                    num = (int) Math.floor((Math.random()*n+1));
                }
                while(!unUsedInBox(row,col,num));
                mat[row + i][col + j] = num;
                }
            }
        }

    boolean checkIfSafe(int r,int c,int num) {
        for(int k = 0;k < n;k++) {
            if(mat[r][k] == num) {
                return false;
                }
            if(mat[k][c] == num) {
                return false;
                }
        }
        int rowstart = r - r%sqn;
        int colstart = c - c%sqn;
        for(int i = 0;i<sqn;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j<sqn;j++) {
                if(mat[rowstart + i][colstart + j] == num) {
                    return false;
                    }
                }
            }

        return true;
        }

    boolean fillRemaining(int r,int c) {
        if (c>=n && r<n-1) { // j>=9 && i < 8
            r = r + 1; 
            c = 0; 
        } 
        if (r>=n && c>=n) // i >= 9 && j >= 9
            return true; 

        if (r < sqn) {  // i < 3 it is to skip the first diagonal 3x3 matrix
            if (c < sqn) // j< 3
                c = sqn; // j = 3
        } 
        else if (r < n-sqn)  {  // i < 6  it is to skip the second diagonal 3x3
            if (c==(int)(r/sqn)*sqn) // j == 3
                c =  c + sqn;   //  j =  6
        } 
        else { 
            if (c == n-sqn)  {  // j ==  6 && i < 9
                r = r + 1; 
                c = 0; 
                if (r>=n) 
                    return true; 
            } 
        } 

        for (int num = 1; num<=n; num++)  { 
            if (checkIfSafe(r, c, num))   { 
                mat[r][c] = num; 
                if (fillRemaining(r, c+1)) { 
                    return true;  }
                mat[r][c] = 0; 
            } 
        } 
        return false; 
     } 

    private void removeKDigits() {
        int count = k;
        while(count != 0) {
            int cellID = (int) Math.floor((Math.random()*(n*n)+1));
            int i = (cellID/n); 
            int j = cellID%n; 
         // if (j != 0) {
           //    j = j - 1; 
             // }
            if(i != n){
                if (mat[i][j] != 0) {
                 count--; 
                 mat[i][j] = 0; 
                  }
             } 
         }
    }


      //  jTextField8.setText(jjj);
    public void printSudoku()  { 
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) { 
                 for (int j = 0; j<n; j++) 
                         System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " "); 
                     System.out.println(); 
              } 
                jTextField1 = new JTextField();

             //   System.out.println(jjj);

               // try {
                //
              //  catch(Exception ex){}
            System.out.println(); 
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) { 
                for (int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
                    System.out.print(mat_sol[i][j] + " "); }
                     System.out.println(); 
              }
    }
```

// editor-fold

```
    public void prant() {
        jjj = Integer.toString(mat[0][0]);
            System.out.println(jjj);
          // jTextField1.setText("loe");
        }

    private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      System.out.println(jjj);     
    }                                        

    private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        dispose();
        xsudoku xs = new xsudoku(pop);
        xs.setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,"Confirm if you wanna to exit","wait wait wait!!!",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        dispose();
        Home home = new Home();
        home.setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */    
                int n = 9;
        int k = 40;
        int[][] mat = new int[n][n];
        Avg_Game sudoku = new Avg_Game(n,k);
        sudoku.fillValue();

        sudoku.printSudoku();
                 sudoku.prant(); 
             //   int j = sudoku.mat[0][0];
              //  System.out.println(j);
            //  sudoku.jTextField17.setText(Integer.toString(j));

        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Avg_Game().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
      //  sudoku.print();
      //  sudoku.jTextField8.setText("game");

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLMain;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLTime;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLTime1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField10;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField11;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;

}
```

Comment: Why are you create 2 instances of `Avg_Game`? Change code to use the `sudoku` variable in the `invokeLater` logic, instead of creating a different instance, which has another instance of the `jjj` field.

Comment: Actually i just made two instances because one instance is to access a string from my another menu.java file and other instance is to generate Sudoku(matrix) in this file. If you can suggest more nicer way to do that .. then please suggest

Comment: I already did suggest, starting with "Change code ..."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is not the global variable. Try the following: make the method jButton6ActionPerformed() public and call it after you call prant() in your main(), as following:

```
    sudoku.jButton6ActionPerformed(null);
```

This will print your updated variable correctly.

<s>I assume the issue you encounter is that either your jButton6ActionPerformed is called to soon, or you don't get a call and you don't see your expected result.</s>

As Andreas correctly pointed it out in the comments, the issue stems from creating a new instance when you create and display your form, instead of using the same instance "sudoku". Therefore replacing the following should fix it:

`new Avg_Game().setVisible(true);`

with

`sudoku.setVisible(true);`

Comment: I am still facing two problems (after following your suggestion)...
     1). It is accessing that variable only once(while it is called in main function) but I want it to access it after pressing 'play' button
     2).How to setText the final value of this variable to JTextFields .

Comment: No, the problem is that `jButton6ActionPerformed` is called when the user presses a button in the JFrame UI *(presumably)*, but that call is on a **different instance** of `Avg_Game` than the call to `prant`. That is because `setVisible(true)` is not called on the `sudoku` instance, but on a `new Avg_Game()`, as already [explained in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893960/global-variable-loses-its-value-after-providing-its-value-in-a-function-unable-t?noredirect=1#comment94634183_53893960).

Comment: Yes, you are right, so my assumption was incorrect, but the issue was indeed not the global variable. I'll update my answer.

Comment: oh!.. Thanks a lot .Yes,you are right ,the problem was the different instances of Avg_Game . It works for me.

Comment: Now a new problem arises i.e., when I write sudoku.setVisible(true); in invoke later logic ,then everything is working fine but i am unable to access the string "om" from its another instance Avg_Game(String om) .
 Value of string "om" should come from another JFrame form i.e., Home.java
code written in Home.java is :
Avg_Game average = new Avg_Game(Player); 
average.setVisible(true);
Please tell me how can I use String "om" from its another instance.

Comment: This seems to be a new question, maybe consider posting it. Nevertheless, I'll try to briefly describe possible solutions. Currently you were creating a new Avg_Game instance via main() with the Avg_Game(n,k). If you want to change this behavior and the application will start from another place, which will then create the Avg_Game() via Home.java or any other class, then you should just use the constructs from the main() inside that Home.java. If you want to add the player name, you could create a constructor having all 3 params: n, k, om.

Comment: If you want to have multiple instances sharing a common field, that would imply more changes depending on what you want to achieve. In this case I recommend to search for existing questions or create a new one.